# Can't add ActionListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

Can you please help me with this code ? How can I make it that when the button is clicked, a second button appears? I've already added the actionlisteners and created the second button, but I can't seem to be able to do it. Thank you soooooooo much everyone!!!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Skeleton extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Hello");

        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(button);        
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        panel.add(button2); //Whenever I compile with this line 
                            //of code inserted, it tells
                            //me cannot find Button 2 
    }    
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This program won't compile.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this GUI. Please debug and let us know what you need help with.

Comment: don't make the class extend Jpanel. It does not make sense. For the panel issue. Move all your code in main to a non-static method. Call this non static method by creating instance of the class. Then make the Panel instance and button2 instance a class level variable.

Comment: I have fixed the JButton not appearing issue. Thanks pravat, I extended the main class with JFrame and it worked. Tdorno and Vishal K, since it now compiles and works fine, can you please help me with the actionlistener? Thank you both soo much, and thanks everyone.

Comment: Just another thing: Pravat, what do you mean by creating an instance of the class? Sorry for this; I'm a total beginner newbie. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedTawfik: Swing is not really the kind of thing to start with in this case, as you'll encounter a mix of concepts that need to be clarified one at a time.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik : __1.)__ Your variables are local to the `main` method, hence the `actionPeformed()` knows nothing of these variables like `panel/button2` (Seems like you sorted this thingy out). __2.)__ Calls like `frame.setSize(...)/frame.setVisible(boolean)` must come at the very last, after you had added all components to the container (In this case, at the end of the `main` method). __3.)__ In your `actionPerformed(...)` method you need to only add `panel.revalidate() and panel.repaint() after panel.add(button2)` to see the new change, on an already visible container.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik : You're MOST WELCOME and __KEEP SMILING :-)__. And the most funny thingy is, you never added the __ActionListener__ to your __button__ for any effect to ever occur (no line that says `button.addActionListener(this)`) __:-)__ Though if still unclear, [here is your modified code version](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/Skeleton.java), with added changes in it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I can't seem to be able to open it. Is there anyway you could post it on some other website, or post it as an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @AhmedTawfik : Please find these links for added information, on various approaches one can take to handle events [__first approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfyly2anqmo7v87/Skeleton.java), [__second approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cso39hh1efpcls/Skeleton1.java) and [__third approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dhwdbfxmcvpsng/Skeleton2.java) and there is one more approach, in my knowledge, but that you can learn as you get more insight into how Swing works, which includes separation of duties, like [MVC-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: @AhmedTawfik : LOL :-), I just remember, there is one more easy approach, I forgot to share with you, have a look at this [__fourth approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/671hqa629pbi95u/Skeleton3.java), as well. And please from next time, while referring to someone through commens add @ (sign Shift + (Digit) 2) and write the person's name, else you won't be able to reach that person's inbox. Do watch how I am sending the messages to you using `@ and your name AhmedTawfik` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many issues. First you can't create/build your UI in the `main()` method
you need to create an instance of the class and call the method from there.

Also for you to be able to refer to `panel` and `button2` you need to make them class objects not local objects inside the UI method.

And you need to at the very least add the `ActionListener` to the `button`

Finally you just need to call `panel.revalidate()` for the panel to show the added button:

```
    public class Skeleton extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Skeleton().buildUI();
    }

    JPanel panel;
    JButton button2;

    public void buildUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        button2 = new JButton("Hello");

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        panel.add(button2); 
        panel.revalidate();

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sammy! An expert answer explaining some stuff :) Just two questions: So revalidate is the same as repaint? And I don't get the instance of a class thing, because everytime I create a component outside the main method, then I call for it inside the main method, the compiler starts giving some static and non-static crap. So what exactly are you doing by adding "public void buildUI()? and new Skeleton().buildUI()? Thank you very much!

Comment: no revalidate is not the same as repaint one is for all components within a component to be validated, the other is for re-rendering the component using either the `paint()` or `update()` method in a `JComponent`. Instance of a class means create a new object from a class, so here you're creating a `new Skeleton()`. What you probably tried was creating a method inside the main, which is not the same.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer, thanks!